# routePrefix is being ignored on Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

It appears the routePrefix is being ignored on my function app. It shows in the console output that the configuration file is being read successfully:

```
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Host configuration file read:
      {
        "version": "2.0",
        "http": {
          "routePrefix": "",
          "maxOutstandingRequests": 20,
          "maxConcurrentRequests": 10,
          "dynamicThrottlesEnabled": false
        }
      }
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Initializing Host.
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Starting JobHost
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Starting Host (HostId=fractalnode-520849571, InstanceId=3e35830d-fd9d-4235-ae6a-7d1b356db04a, Version=2.0.12050.0, ProcessId=36292, AppDomainId=1, Debug=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Starting language worker process:node  "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\dist/src/nodejsWorker.js" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 50880 --workerId 1f503d98-7661-4a40-83cd-ee19d9a48751 --requestId 9a6ef97a-b016-4554-904b-db43e3f4262c --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] node process with Id=36800 started
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Found the following functions:
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Host.Functions.serverTrigger
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM]
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Host initialized (196ms)
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Host started (203ms)
[9/3/18 9:33:52 PM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: c:\proj\directalert\www
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7071/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...
```

but then it still has the /api prefix even though it should be ""

```
Http Functions:
        serverTrigger: http://localhost:7071/api/{*segments}
```

Also, changing the routePrefix to '/' or '/apiprefixtest' doesn't make any difference either.

Any idea why the routePrefix is being ignored by the Azure Functions runtime?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see that you are using Version 2.0. Schema has changed for V2, so just add the "extensions" as shown below:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
        "extensions": {
            "http": {
                "routePrefix": "",
                "maxOutstandingRequests": 20,
                "maxConcurrentRequests": 10,
                "dynamicThrottlesEnabled": false
            }
    }
}
```

There are some breaking changes there in V2, so do take a look at this documentation and you might find some more relevant changes -

[Azure Functions Runtime 2.0.12050-alpha breaking changes notice](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129)

And here is a link from within the article mentioned above specific to application  -

[All application-level extension settings now live under "extensions"](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json-(v2))

Comment: Thank you! I actually was just spelunking through the source code and also noticed that there is a whole bunch of stuff commented out @ https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3377 and asked about it there as well. We'll see what Fabio says - hopefully they can get all this working soon.

Comment: Looks like it is broken again in Functions v3